# Type mismatch: inferred type is PluginRegistry? but FlutterEngine was expected

Tags: flutter, workmanagers

I want to work with Flutter Workmanager, I did the cited configuration in my .kt like this:

```
package com.example.mybackprocess

import be.tramckrijte.workmanager.WorkmanagerPlugin
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class App : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        WorkmanagerPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(reg: PluginRegistry?) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(reg)
    }
}
```

and I have changed `android:name` to

```
android:name=".App"
```

but it gives me this error:

> Launching lib\main.dart on G3212 in debug mode...
> e:E:\mybackprocess\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\mybackprocess\MainActivity.kt:
> (15, 48):  Type mismatch: inferred type is PluginRegistry? but
> FlutterEngine was expected
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.   Compilation
> error. See log for more details
>
> Try:  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
> --info or --debug option to get more   log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 55s  Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code
> 1  Exited (sigterm)

Can someone please help me?

Comment: any answers please ? i still facing this problem

Answer (score 6):

you can fix the issue by replacing the following method in your application.kt

```
override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
    registry?.registrarFor("com.iotecksolutions.background_location_fetch.BackgroundLocationFetchPlugin");
}
```

Note: Replace `com.iotecksolutions.background_location_fetch.BackgroundLocationFetchPlugin` with your plugin name.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the MainActivity.kt with:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code to fix the error
`GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine(applicationContext))`

Answer (score 0):

app this  tag before closing  tag in AndroidManifest like below and you are good to go

```
...
 <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to (JitsiMeetPlugin.kt) file in:
android\src\main\kotlin\com\gunschu\jitsi_meet
JitsiMeetPlugin.kt

**Search for these lines and add (?) to Activity**

```
constructor(activity: Activity) : this() {
        this.activity = activity
    }
```

**And edit it to this:**

```
constructor(activity: Activity?) : this() {
        this.activity = activity
}
```

This Work for me, I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

In **MainActivity.kt** replace to this :

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```